# How to work around Android rotating the BLE Mac Address after every connection?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I'm working on a project where a central device connects to peripherals advertising a specific GATT service. The central device exchanges some information with the phone after which the connection is no longer needed and the device disconnects.

The problem that I'm running into is that the phone seems to change its MAC address after every new connection. So basically, every time I connect to a device it looks like a new device appears. So my central node tries to connect to the new service again. This is very annoying since I was thinking of using the MAC address to know that I had already connected to the device and did not need to do the information exchange again. Note that I know that the MAC address rotates every 30 minutes anyways and that's something I'm willing to deal with, connecting once every 30 minutes is fine, but the rotation on connection causes my device to chain connect to the phone that always appear like a new device.

A few ideas I have thought of to work around this:

1. Obtain the new MAC address from the phone and share it with the central device. That has 2 issues:
2. MAC Address is not accessible with the Android APIs except using sketchy reflection.
3. It would only work if a single central device is in Range, since only the last node would know the new MAC address to avoid.
4. Advertise service Data with a random ID that I would manually rotate every 30 minutes. This data could be in the same advertisement packet. That allows me to ID the device without compromising privacy.
5. It however might be very hard to implement on iOS that has very restrictive background advertisement APIs. iOS doesn't actually appear to have the same behavior though so it might be possible to implement a completely different method for iOS.
6. Disabling this "rotate MAC on connection" feature doesn't seem possible.

How can I work around this issue?

Comment: Do you have Android both as central and peripheral? If not, which side is the Android side and what system is the other side?

Comment: @Emil, The Android phone behaves as the peripheral and advertises the service. My central device that scans and establishes the connection is not a phone and I have full control over it.

Answer (score 1):

If you Bluetooth pair the devices, then the Android device will send over its IRK (Identity Resolving Key). With this you will be able to derive if a given Bluetooth Device Address was generated by the particular IRK or not. That way you can identify an Android device. It works the same if you replace Android with iOS.

See your Bluetooth stack's documentation how to deal with IRKs.

Comment: I see but that requires pairing to be done by the user right? So that couldn't be done entirely in the background when dealing with accessories?

Comment: Yes, but on Android, if pairing is initiated by the Android side, you can use "just works" pairing which requires no user interaction.

Comment: I'm not sure what you refer to with "just works" I tried to pair (initiated by the accessory) but it always prompts something in my app. I don't see a way to initiate the bond from the phone.

Comment: "Just works" is a term defined in the Bluetooth standard. It means that no passkey/displays are used during pairing. See the spec (SMP chapter) for more details how to configure the device so that "just works" will be chosen. Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond() to initiate pairing from Android.